# How do I register an event log so that psloglist can access it?

Tags: windows-7, windows, event-log

This post is about the new sysmon tool from Sysinternals/Microsoft and the event log as relates to psloglist.exe, also from Sysinternals/Microsoft

I'd like to query the sysmon windows event log:
"Applications and Services Logs/Microsoft/Windows/Sysmon/Operational"
with PSLoglist.

On my Windows 7 machine, I can see (psloglist -z):

```
Event logs available on <computername>:
    ActivationClientLibrary
    Application
    Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client
    Dell
    HardwareEvents
    Internet Explorer
    Key Management Service
    Media Center
    ODiag
    OSession
    Security
    Symantec Enterprise Vault
    Symantec Enterprise Vault Converters
    System
    Windows PowerShell
```

According to psloglist, these are the event logs 'registered' on my computer.  Sysmon/Operational is not (yet) included in this list. Because of this, psloglist cannot access this log.

Question:  How do I register this log so that psloglist can gain access to its contents?

Thanks -

Rob

Answer (score 1):

The following is not THE answer but it is my interim workaround...

In event viewer on the sysmon\operational log, right click then

- choose "save all events as..."
- save as an evtx file... e.g. `sysmon.evtx`

I process via

```
psloglist -d 999 -r -s -t \t -x -l sysmon.evtx sys > sysmon.txt
```

It's not what I prefer but it's usable for now.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to automate saving this log file? I have ~100 servers to run this against - so a manual extraction is not really practical -